# Use the Laplace Transform definition to calculate L{f(t)}.

Tags: laplace-transform

Find the Laplace of the given function using the definition

$f(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
-1, & \text { se } 0 \leq t<1 \\
1, & \text { se } t \geq 1
\end{array}\right.$

I know what the answer is according to a sheet that I have of common transforms but I am not 100% on how to get there using the definition

I know that if the question were to be:

f(t) = -1[H(t-0) - H(t-1)] + 1H(t-1)

then it's a simple

$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-s t} * (-1[H(t-0) - H(t-1)] + 1H(t-1))$

but, how to solve this question?

---

what I've been trying:

$\begin{aligned}
& \text { I) } \int_0^1 e^{-s t} u(t) d t=-\int_0^{-1} e^{-s t} d t=\left.\frac{1}{s} e^{-s t}\right|_0 ^1=\frac{1}{s} e^{-s*1}-\frac{1 e^{0*t}}{S}=\frac{e^{-s}-1}{S} \\
& \text { II) } \int_1^{\infty} e^{-s t} u(t) d t=\lim _{A \rightarrow \infty}\left(-\frac{e^{-S A}}{S}+\frac{e^{-S \cdot 0}}{S}\right)=\frac{1}{S} \\
& \rho\{f(t)\}=\frac{e^{-s}}{s} \\
&
\end{aligned}$

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_t[2\, \theta (t-1)-1](s)=\int_0^{\infty } (2\, \theta (t-1)-1)\, e^{-s\, t} \, dt=\frac{2\, e^{-s}-1}{s}$ where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: It appears your mistake is in II where $\frac{e^{-S \cdot 0}}{S}$ should be $\frac{e^{-S \cdot 1}}{S}$ since the integral is from $1\to\infty$ versus $0\to\infty$.

Comment: I checked, that's really what you said. Other than that, is the procedure consistent?

Comment: Assuming $u(t)=f(t)=2\, \theta (t-1)-1$, then with the correction of $\frac{e^{-S \cdot 0}}{S}$ to $\frac{e^{-S \cdot 1}}{S}$ in II which changes the result in II from $\frac{1}{S}$ to $\frac{e^{-S}}{S}$ the procedure seems correct.